# At what electromagnetic frequency does the wavelength = the wave height?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength

At what frequency does the wavelength equal the height of the wave amplitude?

The wave height / amplitude the physical space the wave height occupy in space, similar to the wavelength. My assumption is that the wave height of the basic electromagnetic wave is fixed.

[image]

It is my understanding that, fixed amplitude in E.M. graph can be:

- [Pictures of the electromagnetic spectrum, shows that the amplitude is the same regardless of frequency. what is the amplitude used in these Pictures?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54guv.jpg)
- [The maximum photons emitted by single electron per second.](https://socratic.org/questions/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-photons-emitted-per-second)
- [The minimum photons needed to make light wave ???.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269077/how-many-photons-are-needed-to-make-a-light-wave)

Now, let's ignore the typical E.M. wave graph and only take the wavelength from it. As we know, the E.M. waves propagate from left to right or up to down as mentioned by annav down below and [here](https://youtu.be/fI2C4VlR1OM?t=27). The next step is to calculate the length  of the up to down motion in physical space most likely it will be in Planck and compare it to the wavelength. At what frequency does the wavelength equal the length of the left to right \ up to down motion?

Follow up question: does the length of the up to down motion change with the frequency??

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The amplitude and frequency are not related. Well not unless there is some other constraint on the system that you haven't told us about.

Comment: why it doesn't make sense if you know the height of the wave you can answer it.

Comment: Well, then it depends on that wave height, doesn't it? Any answer can be correct. Are you asking how to calculate wavelength from frequency? That would be $\lambda =v/f$.

Comment: @Steeven how about this, what's the wave height of the electromagnetic wave at any given frequency ?

Comment: The "height" most likely represent the electric field amplitude, which units are volt/meters, the wavelength is measured in meters. It doesn't make sense to compare them. The fact that they could graphically have the same size (it seems to be what you are asking) is just dependent on the scale of the two axis

Comment: What I am getting right now is that there is no way "yet" to measure the wave  height even mathematically ? can somebody explain why.

Comment: First tell us what you understand as the "height" of the wave? 
But sure there are ways to measure it (not going into the details), or compute it given enough information about the source of this wave. But the quantity represented as the height of the wave doesn't have the same units (in the case of E.M. waves) as the wavelength so there is no sense in telling that they are equal.

Comment: @Hammar There isn't just no way "yet".  There is no way in general.  Think of what your wave graph represents.  You have an E.M. signal on the y axis, and time on the x axis.  No matter what you do, time will never be the same units as your E.M. signal; so you can't make the wave height the same as the wavelength.  If you want them the same size on a graph you just scale the graph differently.  The big thing is that the graph you asked about is not showing horizontal distance vs. vertical distance; it is showing a value change over time.

Comment: @David The wave height = the psychical space the waveheight occupy in space, similar to the wavelength. My assumption is that the wave height of the basic electromagnetic wave is fixed.

Comment: @Hammar neither the height nor the wavelength of an electromagnetic wave exists in "physical space" in this representation.  It is an electromagnetic pulse measured over time.

Comment: electromagnetic waves are not like water waves. They have no height in space, the have an intensity in the electric and magntic fields but that is a different phase space

Comment: @ JMac can you explain to me what's the crest & trough of the electromagnetic wave represent why on up and the other down. when we say the wavelength is 1m does that mean it's most intense every 1m.

Comment: There is no connection between  wave height and wavelength. You can have any wavelength for any wave height. It's like asking "*How can I calculate the color of my car from the speed I am driving*". Those two things just aren't related.

Comment: @Hammar It is the electromagnetic pulse.  There is a variation in the electromagnetic field, the "height" of the wave is the maximum value in the electric (or magnetic) field.  It is not a specific height, it is a specific strength that varies with time.  If you had a weaker signal the wave would be "shorter".

Comment: @annav do you mean the wave comes to existence at every crest & trough and disperse from existence in the middle?

Comment: @ JMac how long does the electric (or magnetic) field take to reach the maximum value from the minimum value?

Comment: @Hammar Half of the wavelength.

Comment: @ JMac I meant  in seconds,  but if the maximum value change with the wavelength and frequency than than there is no point.

Comment: @David "The "height" most likely represent the electric field amplitude, which units are volt/meters"what is the "height"/ amplitude unit for the magnetic field and is there amplitude unit for both of them combined (electromagnetic field  amplitude)

Comment: @JMac "You have an E.M. signal on the y axis, and time on the x axis" What do you mean by E.M. signal and what is the unit used?

Answer (score 5):

The electromagnetic wave is not a wave on a medium, as water waves which are coherent variations in position of water molecules.

Electromagnetic waves are built up by photons in coherence , each photon having an energy h*nu where nu is the frequency of the wave that emerges from a large number of photons . ( to get an idea of how many look at my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306975/how-many-atoms-does-it-take-for-us-to-perceive-colour/306978#306978)) .

The photons, as quantum mechanical entities, are described by a wavefunction which is a solution of a quantized maxwell's equation. This wave function has information on the electric an magnetic fields that will be built up in the emergent classical wave.

The emergent classical electromagnetic wave

[image: emwave]

> [The electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) that compose electromagnetic radiation can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This diagram shows a plane linearly polarized EMR wave propagating from left to right (X axis). The electric field is in a vertical plane (Z axis) and the magnetic field in a horizontal plane (Y axis). The electric and magnetic fields in EMR waves are always in phase and at 90 degrees to each other.

This is an instance in time

In the same link there is an animation that shows the [propagation in time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Electromagneticwave3Dfromside.gif).

[image: em]

The [equations](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwv.html#c1) for the electric and magnetic field are:

[image: electricfield]

[image: magneticfield]

and to be consistent solutions of maxwell's equations:

[image: E/B]

The magnitude of the E and B fields, the E_m and B_m depends on the [energy carried](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwv.html#c2) by the specific electromagnetic wave:

As you can see, the wavelength develops in space, but the height of the wave, as everybody has been trying to explain the comments, is not in units of length, but in units of the electric E field and the corresponding units of c*B field. Thus your question has no answer because it compares apples to oranges.

The connection is not simple even in [water waves,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/watwav2.html) whose height is in the units of space.

Comment: "propagating from left to right" is this in psychical space or in imaginary space?

Comment: The x,y,z are in physical space, the E and B are vector functions in this physical space which display the sinusoidal curve. The drawing is an instant in time

Comment: "The magnitude of the E and B fields, depends on the energy carried by the specific electromagnetic wave" this will lead to me to this question: What's the maximum and the minimum energy energy carried by single photon?

Comment: A single photon has no limit in the energy it carries until it hits limits from the planck length, (its frequency will be  nu=E/h.)  See also my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284444/if-energy-is-quantized-does-that-mean-that-there-is-a-largest-possible-waveleng/284445#284445

Comment: see numbers here  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284444/if-energy-is-quantized-does-that-mean-that-there-is-a-largest-possible-waveleng/284445#284445  and you can read the answers,  the differences in opinion come on whether it is a measurable or achievable quantity.

Comment: you have not understood. The up down variation in space is the variation of the E(x) and B(y) in coulombs , nothing to do with a length in space. E(x) means that the E at point x is C number of newtons/coulombs.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field#Definition

Comment: why there is a variation in the electromagnetic field with time why they don't stay constant and average out ? and why the represent half wave with up and  the other half with down ?

Comment: To answer these questions you have to take a classical electrodynamics course and a quantum electrodynamics course, which is outside the scope of questions and answers here. Try the MIT courses https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-physics-ii-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2007  and https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-07-electromagnetism-ii-fall-2012/index.htm

Answer (score -7):

> At what frequency does the wavelength = the height of the wave amplitude ?

At 7.7646 x 10<sup>20</sup> Hz. The associated wavelength and amplitude is 3.861 x 10<sup>−13</sup> m. The electron Compton wavelength is 2.426 × 10<sup>−12</sup> m, which is 2π times this amplitude.

> The wave height = the physical space the waveheight occupy in space, similar to the wavelength. My assumption is that the wave height of the basic electromagnetic wave is fixed.

Correct. Take a look at some pictures of the electromagnetic spectrum, note that the amplitude is the same regardless of frequency, and note that the dimensionality of action h can be expressed as momentum x distance. Also note that the reduced Planck's constant ħ is h divided by 2π.

[image]

It's important to note that an electromagnetic wave is an *electromagnetic wave*. Some people will tell you it's an electric wave and a magnetic wave which generate one another, and therefore no medium is required. That's not true. Check out the Wikipedia [electromagnetic wave article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Derivation_from_electromagnetic_theory) and note this:

*"Also, E and B far-fields in free space, which as wave solutions depend primarily on these two Maxwell equations, are in-phase with each other. This is guaranteed since the generic wave solution is first order in both space and time, and the curl operator on one side of these equations results in first-order spatial derivatives of the wave solution, while the time-derivative on the other side of the equations, which gives the other field"*.

What people call the electric wave is actually the spatial derivative of the electromagnetic wave, while the magnetic wave is actually the time derivative. They are merely two aspects of the same wave, not two different waves. And [as Maxwell said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current#History_and_interpretation), *"light consists of transverse undulations in the same medium that is the cause of electric and magnetic phenomena"*. When an ocean wave travels through the sea, the sea waves. When a seismic wave travels through the ground, the ground waves. When a gravitational wave travels through space, space waves. See [LIGO](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/what-are-gw):

*"Albert Einstein predicted the existence of gravitational waves in 1916 in his general theory of relativity. Einstein's mathematics showed that massive accelerating objects (such as neutron stars or black holes orbiting each other) would disrupt space-time in such a way that 'waves' of distorted space would radiate from the source (like the movement of waves away from a stone thrown into a pond)".*

The same is true for an electromagnetic wave. When an electromagnetic wave travels through space, *space waves*.